# How to send Windows key shortcuts to local machine in mobaxterm

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, mobaxterm

I defined a hotkey for my local windows machine (CTRL + ALT + M) that replaces my cursor in the second monitor.
When connecting to a session in mobaxterm and pressing this hotkey, the session's machine captures the hotkey and the cursors doesn't move, how can I change this behavior?
I was able to change the behavior in windows RDP software by going to "Local Resources" settings and channging "Apply Windows key combinations" to "On this computer". Also on mRemoteNG I was able to do that without a problem.